# Best way to implement multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have seen a few different ways to implement multiprocessing (i.e. by just looping through however many processes you want and creating a Process(), or using multiprocessing.Pool()) and I was just wondering is there a difference between these methods, and would one be better/more efficient than another?

My current project involves splitting a list of hostnames into n sublists and then executing a number of commands on each of those sublists (each within its own process) - what would be the fastest way to go about this? As of right now, the easiest seems to be:

```
def worker(hostList):
    for entry in hostList:
        # DoStuff

def main():
    jobs = []
    for entry in sublists:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(entry,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

Is there any downside to using this method instead of Pool()

Also - just a side note: Why the comma in

```
args=(entry,)
```

Don't understand this syntax but it works fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The downside to the method you show above is that you end up with `N` processes, where `N` is `len(sublists)`. If `sublists` is say, 100 elements long, you end up with 100 concurrently running processes. This puts a huge burden on system memory, and unless you have over 100 cores on your machine, you're just hurting performance, because your can't execute more than `cpu_count()` CPU-bound processes concurrently. That means the OS needs to constantly context switch between the processes to try to get them all some CPU time, which slows you down.

Using `multiprocessing.Pool()` creates a fixed number of processes to do the work (by default [`multiprocessing.cpu_count()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.cpu_count), which means you don't end up with a huge number of processes. This saves memory, and reduces excessive context switching caused by running more tasks than you have cores to process them with.

The trailing comma  in `args=(entry,)` is required because the `args` keyword argument requires an iterable (like a tuple or list). In Python, tuples are created with commas, not parenthesis, so just doing `args=(entry)` is really equivalent to `args=entry`. `entry` isn't necessarily an iterable, so `Process` will do the wrong thing with it. Adding the trailing comma creates a one-element tuple, and keeps `Process` happy. It looks more natural if you have two arguments to pass: `args=(entry1, entry2)`.

Comment: Awesome explanation, thank you! I will use Pool instead as I am taking in as a parameter how many processed to use (if not given, defaulting to cpu_count(). So I will just spawn the desired number of processes and use that method. Thanks!

Comment: @user3403428 No problem. One other note: If your workers are primarily doing I/O-bound tasks - like actually connecting to the hosts in the hosts lists and sending/receiving data to them, you *might* actually get some improvement with a number of workers larger than `cpu_count()`. This is because while the blocking I/O is running, the CPU isn't required. So if you've got 8 workers, and 4 CPUs, you can still be at full capacity without excessive context switching as long as 4 of the workers are doing blocking I/O.

Comment: @user3403428  Note that the above usually only works if some of the workers spend *most* of their time blocking. So even if you're doing I/O in your workers, it may not help you. It's easy enough to tweak the number of processes in your `Pool` to test it various ways, though.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.. What they are actually doing is just executing a batch script remotely through PSexec so there isn't much I/O or sharing of data between the host that I run the script from and the other hosts where the commands are being run